# How to plot multiple lines as histograms per group from a pandas Date Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to look at 'time of day' effects on my users on a week over week basis to get a quick visual take on how consistent time of day trends are. So as a first start I've used this:

```
df[df['week'] < 10][['realLocalTime', 'week']].hist(by = 'week', bins = 24, figsize = (15, 15))
```

To produce the following:

[image]

This is a nice easy start, but **what I would really like is to represent the histogram as a line plot, and overlay all the lines, one for each `week` on the same plot. Is there a way to do this?**

I have a bit more experience with ggplot, where I would just do this by adding a factor level dependency on color and by. Is there a similarly easy way to do this with `pandas` and or `matplotlib`?

Here's what my data looks like:

```
    realLocalTime   week
1   12  10
2   12  10
3   12  10
4   12  10
5   13  5
6   17  5
7   17  5
8   6   6
9   17  5
10  20  6
11  18  5
12  18  5
13  19  6
14  21  6
15  21  6
16  14  6
17  6   6
18  0   6
19  21  5
20  17  6
21  23  6
22  22  6
23  22  6
24  17  6
25  22  5
26  13  6
27  23  6
28  22  5
29  21  6
30  17  6
...     ...     ...
70  14  5
71  9   5
72  19  6
73  19  6
74  21  6
75  20  5
76  20  5
77  21  5
78  15  6
79  22  6
80  23  6
81  15  6
82  12  6
83  7   6
84  9   6
85  8   6
86  22  6
87  22  6
88  22  6
89  8   5
90  8   5
91  8   5
92  9   5
93  7   5
94  22  5
95  8   6
96  10  6
97  0   6
98  22  5
99  14  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simply use `crosstab` to compute the number of element by week and plot it.

```
# Test data
d = {'realLocalTime': ['12','14','14','12','13','17','14', '17'],
 'week': ['10','10','10','10','5','5','6', '6']}
df = DataFrame(d)

ax = pd.crosstab(df['realLocalTime'], df['week']).plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby and value_counts

```
df.groupby('week').realLocalTime.value_counts().unstack(0).fillna(0).plot()
```

[image]